# Android Contact Phone Numbers fetching Duplication

Tags: android, contacts

I can fetch contacts and Phone Numbers of each contact but Phone Numbers are duplicate I think there is some option to show contacts linked with other apps like Viber etc so contact are retrieving duplicated

How can I avoid picking Duplicate Numbers of each contact ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 3) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            contactNumber = "";
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            if (hasPhone.equals("1")) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query
                        (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                        + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("[-() ]", "");
                    contactName=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));


                }
                phones.close();
```

And tell me if this solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using hashmap. You made hashmap of device id to phone number. You add every number into hashmap before checking if hashmap doesnot contain that device id.

Get device id by Querying following URI.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME};

Hashmap<String , Contact > = new Hashmap<String , Contact>();

if (contactHashMap.containsKey(id)) {
   // skip that contact.
}
else {
    //fill your contact object.
    // get device id of contact from mobile                     
       contactHashMap.put(id, contact);
}
```

In this way u can avoid duplicate. There is another way to query other table which gives number to device id. But this cost u two queries. Above hashmap method is efficient and worked well for me.

Comment: I think each contact is linked with SOME ACCOUNT in the address book and we have to pick for default numbers only

Comment: I didnt get you sorry. can u elaborate ur comment